# Erro ao pegar atributo GET em jsp!

Tags: java, jsp, get

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, estou fazendo o seguinte redirecionamento:

```
response.sendRedirect("../../index.jsp?NA=1");
```

Onde a url fica assim:

```
http://localhost:9095/Controle_de_Materiais/index.jsp?NA=1
```

Porém quando tento pegar o atributo, só dá nulo:

```
 <%

        Object obj = request.getAttribute("NA");

        System.out.println("Atributo == " + obj);

        if( obj != null){

             if(Integer.parseInt(obj.toString()) == 1){

               out.println("<p style='float: right;' class='text-danger'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk'></i> Credênciais Inválidas!");

                }

        }
  %>
```

Saída:
[image: Saída do console ao executar]

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Pode postar o código do form por favor?

Comment: Não estou usando form, estou criando a variável diretamente na url! Sou iniciante em jsp, fazia isso em PHP sem problemas, não sei se tem algum problema em jsp.

Comment: Já tentou ao invés de `Object obj = request.getAttribute("NA");` usar `Object obj = request.getParameter("NA");`

Comment: @LaércioLopes Deu certo sua sugestão, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce deve usar:

```
Object obj = request.getParameter("NA");
```

Ao invés de:

```
Object obj = request.getAttribute("NA");
```